# Mapreduce filter data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Consider I have a dataset like below in CSV file:

```
Id, Patient cycle no, counseling
2345, 1, No
1234, 22, Yes
4567, 1, No
2378, 10, No
```

I would like to filter out the records where counseling is 'No' for records with patient cycle = 1, using map-reduce.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using MapReduce in 2021; have you looked at Spark? Also you'll learn better if you try implementing a solution yourself and then post here if you have any problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve the filtering out of the records:

- Using just a `Map` function where we check if the `Patient cycle no` is equal to `1` and `counseling` is equal to `Yes` for every line, without needing any `Reduce` function implementation, and
- Using a `Map` function to put `Patient cycle no` as key and `Id` with `counseling` as a composite value, in order for the data to be grouped by the cycle number so we can then check for every (composite) value if `counseling` is equal to `Yes`.

Since you may have only just started learning about the MapReduce paradigm, I'm going to follow the second way of those two ways, to make the `Map` and `Reduce` functions a bit more clear (**even though the logic of this answer may seem kind off inefficient in terms of scalability and overall speed in execution time, depending of the size and form of the input data**).

The first step is to implement the `Map` function, where all there is to do is reading each record and rearranging the columns of it to put the cycles of the patient as key. In order to protect our hands from getting "dirty" with composite values, the `Id` and `counseling` fields will be put in the value field separated by the `_` character as a delimiter. So the output key-value pairs of the mappers will follow this schema:

`<Patient cycle no, (Id, counseling)>`

For the `Reduce` function, all the key-value pairs have been grouped by key and data with the same key have been put in the same reducer for processing. This basically means that for each patient cycle, all of the `(Id, counseling)` values are stored in the same instance of the `Reduce` function, and we can access them one by one with a simple `for` loop. This is where we:

1. split the composite value with the `_` delimiter,
2. check if we are currently on the reducer with the data grouped for patients with `1` as the number of cycle, and if we are we check if `counseling` is equal to `Yes` to store it to the output
3. store all the other records that have different number of cycles

But when we store the records, it's a good practice to have them resemble the form of the input data, so over here we can rearrange once again the data by putting the patient `Id` as key and `Patient cycle no` with `counseling` as a composite value (here using a delimiter of just a space character  ).

`<Id, (Patient cycle no, counseling)>`

All there are done using something like the source code below (with input data here being put in a folder named `/patients`):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileSplit;

import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class PatientFilter 
{
    /* input:  <byte_offset, line_of_dataset>
     * output: <patient_cycle, (ID, counceling)>
     */
    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> 
    {
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            try 
            { 
                if(value.toString().contains("Patient cycle no"))   // remove header
                    return;
                else 
                {
                    String[] columns = value.toString().split(", ");   // split the columns

                    String id = columns[0];
                    int patient_cycle = Integer.parseInt(columns[1]);
                    String counceling = columns[2];

                    // rearrange the columns to put the cycles as key and the rest as a composite value
                    context.write(new IntWritable(patient_cycle), new Text(id + "_" + counceling));
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /* input: <patient_cycle, (ID, counceling)>
     * output: <ID, (patient_cycle, counceling)>
     */
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, Text>
    {
        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException 
        {
            // for every value grouped by key...
            for(Text value : values)
            {
                String[] split_value = value.toString().split("_");     // split the composite value

                if(key.get() == 1)      // check if the key/patient cycle in this reducer is 1
                {
                    if(split_value[1].equals("Yes"))    // check if counseling for this record is equal to "Yes"
                    {
                        // for patients with just 1 cycle, only store the records that have "counseling" equal to "Yes"
                        context.write(new Text(split_value[0]), new Text(Integer.toString(key.get()) + " " + split_value[1]));
                    }
                }
                else    // store all the other records as well
                    context.write(new Text(split_value[0]), new Text(Integer.toString(key.get()) + " " + split_value[1]));
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // set the paths of the input and output directories in the HDFS
        Path input_dir = new Path("patients");
        Path output_dir = new Path("patients_out");

        // in case the output directory already exists, delete it
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        if(fs.exists(output_dir))
            fs.delete(output_dir, true);

        // configure the MapReduce job
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Patient Filter");
        job.setJarByClass(PatientFilter.class);
        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);    
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, input_dir);
        TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, output_dir);
        job.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

So for the input data seen as below:

```
Id, Patient cycle no, counseling
2345, 1, No
1234, 22, Yes
4567, 1, No
2378, 10, No
4852, 2, Yes
2510, 9, Yes
6564, 5, No
3000, 1, No
6958, 45, No
1500, 1, No
```

The output looks like this:
[image]